# How to use output parameter with StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, wpf, out

I pass a stringbuild out variable to function which parameter type is out stringbuild, but compiler tel me

"Before leave function, You must assign value to sbValue"

```
    public void FuncOutParamString(out StringBuilder sbValue)
    {
        sbValue.Append("wold!");
    }

    private void btnOutParam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=================== Out Parameter ===================");
        // Declare a variable but don't assign a value to it ******************************
        int y = 0;

        // Pass it in as an output parameter, even though its value is unassigned
        FuncOutParamInt(out y);

        // It's now assigned a value, so we can write it out:
        Console.WriteLine(y);

        // Declare a variable but don't assign a value to it ******************************
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Hello ");
        FuncOutParamString(out sb);

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
```

Sorry, I need 10 reputation to post image

Comment: The thing is you don't need to post image in a first place and should post code instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[out] means to be created.
[class] is a reference type.

```
public void FuncOutParamString(StringBuilder sbValue)
{
    sbValue.Append("wold!");
}

public void FuncOutParamStringRef(ref StringBuilder sbValue)
{
    //if(...)
        sbValue = new StringBuilder();
}

public void FuncOutParamStringOut(out StringBuilder sbValue)
{
    sbValue = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the variable sb as StringBuilder you must pass in a value to the constructor else it would be initialized as null. Since it needs to allocate memory from the heap it requires a parameter to use append later on.

You can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for the type of constructor parameter StringBuilder class supports.

This should work:

```
public void FuncOutParamString(StringBuilder sbValue)
{
    sbValue.Append("wold!");
    return sbValue;
}

private void btnOutParam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("=================== Out Parameter ===================");
    // Declare a variable but don't assign a value to it ******************************
    int y = 0;

    // Pass it in as an output parameter, even though its value is unassigned
    FuncOutParamInt(out y);

    // It's now assigned a value, so we can write it out:
    Console.WriteLine(y);

    // Declare a variable but don't assign a value to it ******************************
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(50);
    sb.Append("Hello ");
    sb = FuncOutParamString(sb);

    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

Also you must return the sbValue variable from the FuncOutParamString function.